# Insert Date Into Database Postgres JDBC

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I'm new to Java and also to Postgres.

I have a little project about restaurant and i have a struk(eng: bill) table like this:

[image]

and I have a method to inserting information into that table like this:

```
public int insertBill(int id_karyawan, String tanggal, String waktu, int total) {
    String SQL = "INSERT INTO struk(kode, id_karyawan, tanggal, waktu, total) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
    int id = 0;

    try(Connection conn = connect(); PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(SQL, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS)) {
        pstmt.setInt(1, 1);
        pstmt.setInt(2, id_karyawan);
        pstmt.setString(3, tanggal);
        pstmt.setString(4, waktu);
        pstmt.setInt(5, total);

        int affectedRows = pstmt.executeUpdate();
        if(affectedRows > 0) {
            try(ResultSet rs = pstmt.getGeneratedKeys()) {
                if(rs.next()) {
                    id = rs.getInt(1);
                }
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
    return id;
}
```

later, that method will called with this:

```
int billID = app.insertBill(1, "2017-09-24", "08:00:00", 150000);
```

The problem is, i dont have any idea about the Date and the time, what should i pass as a parameter? what kind of variable so that the query work well? I've searched about it got some clue to use string. I use string on a query method for now. Any advice?

Comment: Use an actual `Date`/`Time` object and let the JDBC driver deal with it

Comment: convert String to Date (SimpleDateFormat) and then use setDate

Comment: If you're on Java 8, and you have the latest JDBC drivers, you should use the `java.time` objects, like `LocalDate` and `LocalTime`, and use `setObject`.

Comment: Why don't you all write this as answer? I thought comments are for questions.

Comment: use `pstmt.setTime(4, ...)` and pstmt.setDate(3, ...)` and use proper `java.sql.Date` or `java.sql.Time` values

Comment: @M.Schwarzer-Haverbier Can't answer for other, but I sometimes do that  because I'm not 100% sure and/or because I don't always have time to flesh out and verify an answer, or because these questions could be easily self-answered by just referencing the API documentation and a proper tutorial.

Answer (score 11):

Since you have said you are new to java, I assume that you would be using Java 8 and The PostgreSQL JDBC driver provides native support for the Java 8 Date and Time API using JDBC 4.2.

Following datatypes for Date/Time are supported by PostgreSQL :

`DATE

TIME [ WITHOUT TIMEZONE ]

TIMESTAMP [ WITHOUT TIMEZONE ]

TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE`

You can use the LocalDate, LocalTime, LocalDateTime or OffsetDateTime (OffsetDateTime is an immutable representation of a date-time with an offset eg:the value "20th July 2017 at 10:45.24.123456789 +04:00" can be stored in an OffsetDateTime). These classes comes in the java.time package, which was introduced in Java 8, as a new Date-Time API.(It covers several cons of old date-time API like design issues, thread safety, time zone handling issues etc.) However, ZonedDateTime, Instant and OffsetTime / TIME [ WITHOUT TIMEZONE ] are currently not supported in PostgreSQl (as in JDBC 4.2). Now comming to programming part based on you code, you can do it like this.

```
public int insertBill(int id_karyawan, String tanggal, String waktu, int total) {

LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now(); //or whatever date you want to use, for passing parameter as string you could use 

                        /*public static LocalDate parse(CharSequence text,
                          DateTimeFormatter formatter)*/

 //   LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of(2017, Month.JULY, 20);
 LocalTime lt = LocalTime.of(8, 0, 0); 

String SQL = "INSERT INTO struk(kode, id_karyawan, tanggal, waktu, total) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
int id = 0;

try(Connection conn = connect(); PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(SQL, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS)) {
pstmt.setInt(1, 1);
pstmt.setInt(2, id_karyawan);
pstmt.setObject(3, localDate);
pstmt.setObject(4, lt);
pstmt.setInt(5, total);

pstmt.executeUpdate(); 
pstmt.close();
```

---

Hope this helped you. In case you are using Java versions below 8, you could use joda time.

Comment: Actually the Joda-Time project is in maintenance mode. The team advises moving to the Java.time classes. As for Java 6 and Java 7, much of the java.time functionality is back-ported in the *ThreeTen-Backport* project.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you:

```
public int insertBill(int id_karyawan, String tanggal, String waktu, int total) {
String SQL = "INSERT INTO struk(kode, id_karyawan, tanggal, waktu, total) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
int id = 0;

try(Connection conn = connect(); PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(SQL, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS)) {
    pstmt.setInt(1, 1);
    pstmt.setInt(2, id_karyawan);
    pstmt.setDate(3, java.sql.Date.valueof("2017-09-24")); 
    pstmt.setTime(4, java.sql.Time.valueof("08:00:00")); 
    pstmt.setInt(5, total);

    int affectedRows = pstmt.executeUpdate();
    if(affectedRows > 0) {
        try(ResultSet rs = pstmt.getGeneratedKeys()) {
            if(rs.next()) {
                id = rs.getInt(1);
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
}
return id;

}
```